# Asynchronous loading and UITableView's -reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, gdata-api

I currently try to figure out why the following code snippet produces an error. I am using the Google Calendar API to load calendars. However I assume that it's loading its data asynchronously and therefore when I call -reloadData my app crashes without console errors.

```
[[GDataHandler sharedDataHandler] fetchCalendarsWithCompletion:^(GDataFeedBase *feed) {


     //CRASH !!! Trying to execute code on main thread
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        for(GDataEntryCalendar *cal in feed.entries){

            if([cal isKindOfClass:[GDataEntryCalendar class]]){
                NSLog(@"adding %@", cal.title.stringValue);
                [calendarArray addObject:cal];
            }

        }

        [list reloadData];

    });

}];
```

Backtrace looks like this:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xeabe5, 0x39ed81fc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x39ed81fc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x39f3fa52 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 58
    frame #2: 0x39e8902c libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 76
    frame #3: 0x392d798e libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 74
    frame #4: 0x392f06e6 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 254
    frame #5: 0x39928938 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 192
    frame #6: 0x392ee1b2 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #7: 0x392edd16 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 102
    frame #8: 0x3992880e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 42
    frame #9: 0x2f5615b6 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 642
    frame #10: 0x2f561322 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #11: 0x342982ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
    frame #12: 0x31e181e4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
    frame #13: 0x000b8e44 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d54d0c) + 116 at main.m:16
    frame #14: 0x39e21ab6 libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

Here are the delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return calendarArray.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *cellId = @"CellIdentifier";
    CustomListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell == nil){

        cell = [[CustomListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];

    }

    cell.calendar = [calendarArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: please post your UITableViewDelegate methods, they could be the reason.

Comment: @Muhammad added delegate methods :-)

Comment: Side note: Crash occurs before the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method...

Comment: I fear, the reason of the crash is somewhere else in your code not shown. The shown code otherwise, looks OK for me. You need to provide more info, e.g. more about the exception (add an exception breakpoint in Xcode), and what exactly is property `entries` of feed. Another *potential* source of the problem is that the completion handler gets erroneously called while the underlaying task is still running.

Comment: your delegate methods seem OK, and the crash happens in `[list reloadData]`, that's strange, are you sure you pass the `for` loop safely ?

Comment: @Muhammad yes I'm sure. If I execute the code without `-reloadData` everything works fine...

Comment: try returning 0 in `numberOfRowsInSection` method, is it still crashing ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here.

First, when you call `dispatch_get_main_queue()` you actually get back the main thread, which is not ideal for background processing.

So you need to change that to:

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    ... process your data here ...
});
```

The second problem is that you cannot call `UITableView#reloadData` from a background thread. So you actually need to schedule just that one on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [list reloadData];
});
```

The above code for `reloadData` would go in the block where you processed your data, so your completion block for `fetchCalendarsWithCompletion` would be something like:

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    ... process your data here ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [list reloadData];
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand your answer correctly... I understand that `-reloadData` must not be called from a background queue, but the whole block is executed in a background queue, that is why (in my question) I wrapped around the dispatch block for the main queue.

Comment: This answer is more of a performance optimization and doesn't specifically address the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a console log, something like:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ...
```

The stack trace tells us, that an exception has been thrown and caught within the run loop. The run loop then can nothing do than to re-throw it. The exception happens somewhere in your completion block.

In order to catch an exception, you can set a symbolic breakpoint at symbol `objc_exception_throw`, or use Xcode's UI to setup an exception breakpoint: [Adding an Exception Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH1-SW1).

I suspect, another thread is altering the array while you iterating over it.

Comment: I'll add a couple of breakpoints and report back... However, I am pretty sure the array is not being altered while the iteration occurs, because this is the only place calendarArray is used and the completion handler is only executed once. So it is strange indeed.